# WorldWind Sphere Line Intersection Bug?

Tags: java, computational-geometry, intersection, worldwind

I'm seeing what appears to be contradictory behavior out of WorldWind's [Sphere](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/blob/c484f0aac8c4fc5c22aeb99ddef95c6ad4d5dc49/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/Sphere.java)-Line intersection logic. I create a Sphere and Line and they intersect but then the intersection returns null (scan code for comment: // *** This is where it gets whacky).

Here is what's going on visually (the line is gray it's there but hard to see): [image: Sphere-Line Intersecting]

```
public class WWTest extends ApplicationTemplate {

    public static class VisualizationFrame extends ApplicationTemplate.AppFrame {

        public VisualizationFrame() {
            super(new Dimension(1200, 1024));
            final Globe globe = getWwd().getModel().getGlobe();

            //Create a sphere at 0,0 on the surface of the Earth wtih a 60 NMi radius
            final Vec4 sphereCenter = globe.computePointFromLocation(LatLon.ZERO);
            final Sphere sphere = new Sphere(sphereCenter, 111120);
            // Draw the sphere
            final RenderableLayer sphereLayer = new RenderableLayer();
            sphereLayer.addRenderable(sphere);

            final RenderableLayer pathLayer = new RenderableLayer();
            // Create a line at 10k feet (3048 meters) that starts outside the sphere at (2,-2) and proceeds into the sphere at (0.5, 0.5)
            final Position lineStart = Position.fromDegrees(2, -2, 3048);
            final Position lineEnds = Position.fromDegrees(0.5, 0.5, 3048);
            final Path asPath = new Path(lineStart, lineEnds);
            pathLayer.addRenderable(asPath);

            // Now that we've visualized the line, let's do some intersection math
            final Vec4 lineStartsAsVec = globe.computePointFromPosition(lineStart);
            final Vec4 lineEndsAsVec = globe.computePointFromPosition(lineEnds);
            final Line asLine = Line.fromSegment(lineStartsAsVec, lineEndsAsVec);

            // *** This is where it gets whacky - true, but no intersection?
            final boolean doesIntersect = sphere.intersects(asLine);
            final Intersection[] intersection = sphere.intersect(asLine);
            //outputs: Intersection found: null
            System.out.println(doesIntersect ? "Intersection found: " + Arrays.toString(intersection) : "No intersection, Why Not!?!?"); 

            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), sphereLayer);
            insertBeforeCompass(getWwd(), pathLayer);
            getWwd().getView().setEyePosition(Position.fromDegrees(0, 0, 500_000));
            getLayerPanel().update(getWwd());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationTemplate.start("World Wind Sphere-Line Intersection", VisualizationFrame.class);

    }
}
```

And here are the dependencies I declared to get WorldWind into my maven project (I also did try version '2.0.0-986', but that didn't seem to help):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>gov.nasa</groupId>
    <artifactId>worldwind</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>gov.nasa</groupId>
    <artifactId>worldwindx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
    <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

To be completely thorough, here are the code imports:

```
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Intersection;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.LatLon;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Line;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Position;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Sphere;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.geom.Vec4;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.globes.Globe;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.RenderableLayer;
import gov.nasa.worldwind.render.Path;
import gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate;
import static gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate.insertBeforeCompass;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Comment: The primary technical POC of worldwind has been contacted and said this bug will be put in their queue to be fixed. Thanks for your help Chris and Kyle :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `Sphere#intersect()` it is expecting the line in coordinates centered at the sphere's origin (not the Earth's) which is almost certainly a bug. You should be able to do:

```
final Vec4 pa = lineStartsAsVec.subtract3(sphereCenter);
final Vec4 pb = lineEndsAsVec.subtract3(sphereCenter);
final Line asLine2 = Line.fromSegment(pa, pb);
final Intersection[] intersection = sphere.intersect(asLine2);
```

Keep in mind that the intersections returned are still in Cartesian coordinates centered at the sphere's origin, so to transform them back to World Wind Cartesian you need to do:

```
final Vec4 intersectionPos = intersection[0].getIntersectionPoint().add3(sphereCenter);
```

The implementation also considers the line to be infinitely long so it will return two points, not one.

It would be pretty straight forward to implement your own version of `intersect()` that works in normal coordinates and takes into account the length of the line, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection).

Comment: @Chris_K if you're available/interested in helping write some challenging efficient WGS-84 computational geometry routines please shoot me a message, I should be easy to find on FB, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Worldwind source code](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/download-release.asp), specifically the intersects() and intersect() methods of the Sphere class and step through them with your code as input, you see the following:

The method:

```
public boolean intersects(Line line)
```

returns true because the distance from the sphere centre to the line is less than the radius of the sphere, as expected.

For the method:

```
public final Intersection[] intersect(Line line)
```

it turns out that the discriminant of the quadratic is less than zero (i.e. there are no real roots to the quadratic equation - two distinct complex roots).

The WorldWind API reference is [here](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.5/docs/api/index.html).

The specific methods involved are:

```
    /**
 * Tests for intersection with a <code>Line</code>.
 *
 * @param line the <code>Line</code> with which to test for intersection
 *
 * @return true if <code>line</code> intersects or makes a tangent with the surface of this <code>Sphere</code>
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>line</code> is null
 */
public boolean intersects(Line line)
{
    if (line == null)
    {
        String msg = Logging.getMessage("nullValue.LineIsNull");
        Logging.logger().severe(msg);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
    }
    return line.distanceTo(this.center) <= this.radius;
}
```

and:

```
    /**
 * Obtains the intersections of this sphere with a line. The returned array may be either null or of zero length if
 * no intersections are discovered. It does not contain null elements and will have a size of 2 at most. Tangential
 * intersections are marked as such. <code>line</code> is considered to have infinite length in both directions.
 *
 * @param line the <code>Line</code> with which to intersect this <code>Sphere</code>
 *
 * @return an array containing all the intersections of this <code>Sphere</code> and <code>line</code>
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if <code>line</code> is null
 */
public final Intersection[] intersect(Line line)
{
    if (line == null)
    {
        String message = Logging.getMessage("nullValue.LineIsNull");
        Logging.logger().severe(message);
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }

    double a = line.getDirection().getLengthSquared3();
    double b = 2 * line.selfDot();
    double c = line.getOrigin().getLengthSquared3() - this.radius * this.radius;

    double discriminant = Sphere.discriminant(a, b, c);
    if (discriminant < 0)
        return null;

    double discriminantRoot = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
    if (discriminant == 0)
    {
        Vec4 p = line.getPointAt((-b - discriminantRoot) / (2 * a));
        return new Intersection[] {new Intersection(p, true)};
    }
    else // (discriminant > 0)
    {
        Vec4 near = line.getPointAt((-b - discriminantRoot) / (2 * a));
        Vec4 far = line.getPointAt((-b + discriminantRoot) / (2 * a));
        return new Intersection[] {new Intersection(near, false), new Intersection(far, false)};
    }
}
```

which uses:

```
    /**
 * Calculates a discriminant. A discriminant is useful to determine the number of roots to a quadratic equation. If
 * the discriminant is less than zero, there are no roots. If it equals zero, there is one root. If it is greater
 * than zero, there are two roots.
 *
 * @param a the coefficient of the second order pronumeral
 * @param b the coefficient of the first order pronumeral
 * @param c the constant parameter in the quadratic equation
 *
 * @return the discriminant "b squared minus 4ac"
 */
private static double discriminant(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return b * b - 4 * a * c;
}
```

in this case your code fails the:

```
if (discriminant < 0)
```

test.

It looks like I've been a bit slow in answering this question, and in the meantime it has been pointed out by Chris K that this is due to the intersect() method expecting the line coordinates to be centered at the origin of the sphere and not of Earth.

As Chris K said, this seems to be a bug and should probably be logged with the maintainers of this source code.